# Office 365 and Sharepoint apps

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, ms-access-2013, office365-apps

is there a way to create a access web app and use as database an azure sql database. and use it as the main application database or a secondary one.
Either is it possible to create a database that is shared over more than one sharepoint app.

Last but not least is there a way to catch the visitors microsoft mail and use it in a macro to change the views depending on the accesslevel we want him to have on our app.So we can create for example user based profile, either with that way or with creating a user login and registration form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to create a access web app and use as database an azure sql database

When you design and modify in Access 2013 or later, the data and database objects are stored in SQL Server or Microsoft Azure SQL Database, so you can share the data within your organization using on-premises SharePoint 2013 or Office 365 for business.

> Last but not least is there a way to catch the visitors microsoft mail

You could use the Access Custom Web App Function to get the email address , it could be used in user interface (UI) macros .

[UserEmailAddress Function (Access custom web app)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn142191.aspx)